# Passenger start rails app after server reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

How to tell passenger, that it must start after reboot, and start rails app...
Now i do this manually:

```
passenger start
```

But how, and what to configure in ngnix + passenger, that my app start automatically after server is rebooted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Ubuntu, or a similar Linux distro, you'll want an init.d script to start passenger at boot.  See:  [Starting Standalone Passenger on startup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phusion-passenger/2W0Z-mRabq4)

Comment: It seems the procedure described in the link is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

its late. but could be useful to someone else. Add the command to cron.

```
crontab -e
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/app && passenger start'
```